# jQuery Ajax is not Working what is the Issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

jQuery for Updating Database table entry using PHP. after ajax code is not working for me please help.

```js
$("#dynamic-table").on("click", ".submit", function () {
    var rowID = $(this).attr("id");
    var allottedValue = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    alert('Row id = ' + rowID + ' Enrollment no = ' + allottedValue);

    var dataString = 'allottedEnroll=' + allottedValue + '&rowid=' + rowID;

   // After this line it is not working
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "request/allot_enrollmentNo_gov.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (html) {
            $(this).parents(".success1").replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
    //$(this).parents(".success1").animate({backgroundColor: "#003"}, "slow").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow");
});
```

```html
// HTML to Show Multiple Inputbox for multiple upload with link

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic-table">
    <div class="success1">
        <input name="enrollNo" type="text" value="" class="postEnroll"/> 
        <br/>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="TakeFromDB" class="text-success submit">Allot Enrollment No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more detail than 'it's not working'. Have you checked the console for errors? Is the server code being executed?

Comment: Sir this code is use for allotting Enrollment No to a Student.
Their is many rows for Allotment. That's why I am showing many input box with "Allot Enrollment" Link to Allot each row by using Ajax.

Comment: How to check Control is going inside Ajax or Not

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replace with parent, it must be child. Use below code

```
success: function (html) {
   $("#dynamic-table .success1").replaceWith(html);
}
```

OR

```
success: function (html) {
   $("#dynamic-table").find(".success1").replaceWith(html);
}
```

Comment: Sir my Ajax request is not going in  "request/allot_enrollmentNo_gov.php" File. What is the Issue My PHP code is 
<?php
include_once '../includes/connection.php';

if ($_POST['rowid'] && $_POST['allottedEnroll']) {    
    $allottedEnroll = $_POST['allottedEnroll'];
    $rowid = $_POST['rowid'];
    $enrolldate = date('Y-m-d');

    $sqlenr = "UPDATE 'gov_student' SET enrollmentid='$allottedEnroll', enrollDate='$enrolldate' WHERE id='$rowid'";
    $resultenr = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlenr);

    if ($resultenr) {
        echo $allottedEnroll;
    }
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

This code works great i have used similar.... try this one..

```
function FormSubmit() {    
    $.ajax(
      type: "POST", 
      url: 'success1.php',
      data: $("#attend_data").serialize(),
      async: false 
      }).done(function( data ) {
          $("#attend_response").html(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code snippet below... tested offline and the code is working:

A few pointers:

Instead of this: `request/allot_enrollmentNo_gov.php`

Try this: `/request/allot_enrollmentNo_gov.php`

Notice the forward slash `( / )` This indicate that the Ajax path must start from the root directory depending on your server settings.

Use this: `$(".success1").html(html);` instead of `$(this).parents(".success1").replaceWith(html);`

Working code below:

```js
    $("#dynamic-table").on("click", ".submit", function () {
        var rowID = $(this).attr("id");
        var allottedValue = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
        alert('Row id = ' + rowID + ' Enrollment no = ' + allottedValue);

        var dataString = 'allottedEnroll=' + allottedValue + '&rowid=' + rowID;

       // After this line it is not working
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/request/allot_enrollmentNo_gov.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (html) {
                $(".success1").html(html);
                alert('Response from the POST page = ' + html + ');
            }
        });
        //$(this).parents(".success1").animate({backgroundColor: "#003"}, "slow").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow");
    });
```

```html
// HTML to Show Multiple Inputbox for multiple upload with link

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic-table">
    <div class="success1">
        <input name="enrollNo" type="text" value="" class="postEnroll"/> 
        <br/>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="TakeFromDB" class="text-success submit">Allot Enrollment No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working Perfectly by setting parent:

```
$("#dynamic-table").on("click", ".submit", function () {
   var rowID = $(this).attr("id");
   var rowParent = $(this).parent('.success1');
   var allottedValue = rowParent.find('input').val();

   var dataString = 'allottedEnroll=' + allottedValue + '&rowid=' + rowID;
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "request/allot_enrollmentNo_gov.php",
       data: dataString,
       success: function (html) {
           rowParent.replaceWith(html);
       }
   });
   return false;
});
```